# adding/subtract random number to variable

Tags: php, random

I want to create some random sql data with a php script

currently I get the last record, generate a random number between 1 and 2 ... if its a 1 I will add a random number to the record else if its a 2 i will subtract a random number from

the problem is it keeps spitting out minus random numbers! I only want positive random numbers.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Data ORDER BY id DESC") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table

    $temp=$row['temp'];
    $light=$row['light'];

};

$name="Herbi";
$date=Date("o:m:d");
$time=Date("H:i:s");

$rand =rand(1,2);
$randnu =rand(1,10);

echo " rand:".$rand;
switch($rand){

    case 1:
        $temprand=$temp+$randnu;
        $lightrand=$light+$randnu;
    break;

    case 2:
        $temprand=$temp-$randnu;
        $lightrand=$light-$randnu;
    break;
};
echo"";
echo"randnu";
echo $randnu;
echo "   ";
echo"lightrand";
echo $lightrand;
```

Comment: So give `rand()` a "range" that is smaller than the variable, you substract from.

Comment: … or use [`abs`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php). But it depends on the use case and the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean with "spitting out minus random numbers" ? What numbers are negative and where do you "spit them out" ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code this is valid, if your $temp=1 and $rand=2 then $temprand will be -1.

You can add a check that your $temp and $light should always be greater than or equal the max random numbers so when you minus the (max of) random number from $temp or $light you will end up with 0.

```
if($row['temp']>=2){
  $temp=$row['temp'];
}else{
  $temp=2; //Max of $rand =rand(1,2);
}
```

or shorthand

```
$temp=($row['temp'] >= 2? $row['temp'] : 2);
$light=($row['light'] >= 10? $row['light'] : 10);
```

Comment: But even when I start the initial values at 25 it suddenly jumps to -9  ... and it seems that $randnu and $lightrand are equal

Comment: What goes to -9? lightrand or temprand?